# I cant log-in with Google with my second account

Tags: flutter, oauth-2.0, google-signin, google-authentication, google-authenticator

When Im login with google to my flutter app and let say that I realize that this is a wrong google account with wrong gmail, photo etc. so I logout and try to login with google with another account but It impossible because Im just automatically being login with this previous account. Maybe there is some way to logout completely ?

This is a code where I'm signOut:

```dart
  Future<void> signOutFromGoogle() async {
    await _googleSignIn.signOut();
    await _auth.signOut();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You Need to sign out from 2 different instances.

```
await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut()
await GoogleSignIn().signOut()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to sign out from Google in addition to Firebase.

https://pub.dev/documentation/google_sign_in/latest/google_sign_in/GoogleSignIn/signOut.html

Comment: I'm doing it:
  Future<void> signOutFromGoogle() async {
    await _googleSignIn.signOut();
    await _auth.signOut();
  }

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to invoke "disconnect" method ! Sign-out is not enough.